# How to remove warning from the server log: [WARN] No configuration found for the specified action: '/' in namespace: ''

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, web.xml

I have developed a application using struts 2.0. On the server log I am getting certain warning lines. I want to fix this warnings but I am not able to do it.

```
[WARN] No configuration found for the specified action: '/' in namespace: ''. Form    action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
```

In my struts.xml file I have something like this

```
<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
<global-results>
<result name="error">/error.jsp </result>
</global-results>
<action name="Login" class="com.login.LoginAction">
        <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/dashboard.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

In the jsp page I am calling following javascript function on click of a button

```
function submitloginform()
    {
        document.loginform.action = "Login.action";
        document.loginform.submit();
    }
```

Can anyone please help me for this.

Comment: Assign action to your form.

Comment: I need to do validation at client side so before submitting the form I am doing it in javascript and then submitting the form

Comment: Do you have action attribute in form tag?

Comment: No, I am not having action attribute in form                 <s:form name="loginform" method="post" onsubmit="submitloginform()">

Comment: So just add it. `<s:form name="loginform" method="post" onsubmit="submitloginform()" action="Login">`

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr M..It is working. I will check it in other browsers...Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just keep action name in struts.xml and action of form to be submitted same.

```
function submitloginform()
    {
        document.loginform.action = "Login";
        document.loginform.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This warning message has nothing to do with the javascript or the form submission. It happens when the  tag is rendered to the it's  representation in HTML.

You must be missing the action attribute in your  in your case. Make sure that your code looks like the following.

`<s:form name="loginform" method="post" action="Login">`

If you are trying to render a form in another namespace, for example: **/public**, you should be doing

`<s:form name="loginform" method="post" action="Login" namespace="/public">`

instead of

`<s:form name="loginform" method="post" action="/public/Login">`